# Make PlatformFile into File in Flutter using File Picker

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-dependencies, filepicker

I am using the File Picker Plugin to choose a file from a device. The file is chosen in the datatype of a PlatformFile, but I want to send the file to Firebase Storage and I need a regular File for that. How can I convert the PlatformFile into a File so that I can send it to Firebase Storage? Here is the code:

```
PlatformFile pdf;
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

void _trySubmit() async {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
    if (isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('article_pdf')
          .child(title + '-' + author + '.pdf');
      await ref.putFile(pdf).onComplete; // This throws an error saying that The argument type 'PlatformFile' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'
    }
  }

void _pickFile() async {
    FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['pdf'],
    );
    if (result != null) {
      pdf = result.files.first;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
PlatformFile pdf;
final File fileForFirebase = File(pdf.path);
```

Happy coding! :)

Comment: This doesn't work on Flutter Web as `PlatformFile.path` is not available on web.

Comment: @lenz - maybe, I've used it only on mobile devices (Androis and IOS).

Comment: @RobertRobinson  It works on web, you have to add the path, name and size I think.

Comment: it will not work with web

Comment: Will not work on web. And also PlatformFile.path returns a String while File() expects a Path

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a web app, you can post image files to Firestore with flutter_file_picker: (Taken from the FAQ page): https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/FAQ

```
// get file
final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.any, allowMultiple: 
false);

if (result.files.first != null){
  var fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes;
  var fileName = result.files.first.name;

  // upload file
  await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('uploads/$fileName').putData(fileBytes);
}
```

Comment: This should be added to the accepted answer to have a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) if you have multiple files you can do:

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);

if (result != null) {
  List<File> files = result.paths.map((path) => File(path)).toList();
} else {
  // User canceled the picker
}
```

NB: I am not sure that it would work with Flutter Web. It should work with all the other platforms.

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
File(platformFile.name)
```

Just be sure not duplicates in the file names in your logic.